# How to use timestamp type parameters set in pipeline with timestamp type in data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I can't send the question due to some mysterious error, so I'll share a screenshot of the question.

Can anyone help me solve this?

[image: ss of the error]

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got same error when the Expression checkbox in checked.

[image]

**Remove the Expression checkbox check** in dataflow pipeline assignment and pass it as a string. Now it won't give the error.

[image]

It will take the Dataflow parameter like this.

[image]

Also, along with the Date time string pass the format in `toTimestamp()` function to avoid null values.

**This is my sample input data:**

[image]

**sample filter condition:**

```
toTimestamp(start_date,'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss')
```

[image]

**Filtered Result:**

[image]